# The dictionary is filled with the same values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, xlrd

I have a table from where I take all the information to fill all these dictionaries, however, in the end all the keys have the same values. Why is this happening? How can this be fixed?

```py
book = xlrd.open_workbook("1k.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
num_cols = sheet.ncols
num_rows = sheet.nrows
groups_list = []
for col_index in range(num_cols):
    group_cell = str(sheet.cell(1, col_index).value)
    if "-18" in group_cell:
        groups_list.append(group_cell)
groups_list = dict.fromkeys(groups_list, [
        dict.fromkeys(["ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК", "ВТОРНИК", "СРЕДА", "ЧЕТВЕРГ", "ПЯТНИЦА", "СУББОТА"], dict.fromkeys(["1 пара", "2 пара", "3 пара", "4 пара", "5 пара", "6 пара"], dict.fromkeys(["Предмет", "Преподаватель", "Аудитория", "Вид занятия"]))),
        dict.fromkeys(["ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК", "ВТОРНИК", "СРЕДА", "ЧЕТВЕРГ", "ПЯТНИЦА", "СУББОТА"], dict.fromkeys(["1 пара", "2 пара", "3 пара", "4 пара", "5 пара", "6 пара"], dict.fromkeys(["Предмет", "Преподаватель", "Аудитория", "Вид занятия"])))])

for col_index in range(num_cols):
        for group in groups_list.keys():
                if group == str(sheet.cell(1, col_index).value):
                        row_index = 3
                        for day, couples in groups_list[group][0].items():
                                for couple in couples.keys():
                                        groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Предмет'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value)
                                        groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Вид занятия'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index+1).value)
                                        groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Преподаватель'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index+2).value)
                                        groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Аудитория'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index+3).value)
                                        row_index += 2
```

In the last loop I output the information that was assigned to the keys there, however, if it is output in other loops or outside the loops, then the output will be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in dict.fromkeys(). Because of it all keys have same reference